# Copy all photos on an entire drive in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, copy, rename, archive

I have a drive that mounts at /run/media/jeremy/MONSTER that has a ton of old backups of aperture libraries, iPhoto libraries, and general backups of home directories from the years.

I'd like to track down every gif, jpg, jpeg, and cannon raw file and copy them to /run/media/jeremy/1.4t_Video/photos and optimally have them given a unique name based on the file creation date. I assume bash is up to the task, but not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Take a look at the powerful `find` utility. Start by reading its man page: `man find`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find /run/media/jeremy/MONSTER \( -iname \*.gif -o -iname \*.jpg -o -iname \*.jpeg \) -exec cp {} /run/media/jeremy/1.4t_Video/photos/ \;
```

this should find all files ending in those extensions and copies them over to /run/media/jeremy/1.4t_Video/photos/

if you want to add more extensions just use -o -iname *.

Comment: You should try to explain what this is doing

Answer (score 1):

You could use a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
serial=0
find /run/media/jeremy/MONSTER \( -iname \*.gif -o -iname \*.jpg -o -iname \*.jpeg -o -iname \*.cr2 \) -print0 |
   while read -r -d '' f; do

      # Get its extension, like "jpg" or "cr2"
      ext=${f##*.}

      # Get its date of creation like "2012-01-07 11:06:45"
      datetime=$(stat --printf="%w" "$f" | sed 's|\..*||')

      # Formulate a new name
      new="/output/dir/${datetime}-${serial}.${ext}"

      # Show what we came up with
      echo Would copy $f to $new
      # cp "$f" "$new"

      ((serial++))
   done
```

At the moment it does nothing, it just shows you what it would do. Uncomment the 3rd to last line, by removing the `#` in front of `cp` if it looks correct. Please make a backup first and test with a small number of files...

**Sample Output**

```
Would copy ./b.jpg to /output/dir/2016-02-11 10:40:58-0.jpg
Would copy ./mosaic/0.jpg to /output/dir/2016-02-08 12:36:06-1.jpg
Would copy ./mosaic/1.jpg to /output/dir/2016-02-08 12:36:07-2.jpg
Would copy ./mosaic/10.jpg to /output/dir/2016-02-08 12:36:12-3.jpg
Would copy ./mosaic/100.jpg to /output/dir/2016-02-08 12:36:41-4.jpg
Would copy ./mosaic/101.jpg to /output/dir/2016-02-08 12:36:42-5.jpg
Would copy ./mosaic/102.jpg to /output/dir/2016-02-08 12:36:42-6.jpg
Would copy ./mosaic/103.jpg to /output/dir/2016-02-08 12:36:42-7.jpg
```